# How to create a Time Picker

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I need to use a time picker.
I found a lot of solution, like field or numeric stepper but for me all are worse. The better seems to be field but how constrain user to input only number before and after ":".

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Before anyone can help you build a Time Picker you have to define how you expect the time picker to work.  Screenshots, or mockups, or descriptions of the user interaction are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Flex 4.6 has a [DateSpinner](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS7dd5c1363434bb702fbebf5a1312e95e4e3-8000.html) component which provides date, time and date/time input features.  The problem is that the component is part of mobile component.  To enable that component for regular flex project is possible, just search for mobile.swc, mobiletheme.swc in Flex SDK, and add them as part of your Flex project.

This is a quick but may not be the most elegant solution, but at least you could get it up and running within minutes.

Update: Alternatively, you may consider Yahoo's [Astra TimeInput component](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flex/timeinput/), it is written as mx component, but should still work well in spark application.

Answer (score -2):

i have used [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) timepicker jquery addon in my recent projects, it is awesome.

Comment: I think the question is pertaining to Flex, and I am not sure jQuery or jQuery addon can run within Flex.

Comment: I didn't looked at those tags.